# typed.js doesn't work for the second attempt

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, typed

The first attempt to hover *div.logo* finish successfully and *typed.js* types the sentence. After that, when hover again on *div.logo* it doesn't work and doesn't type anything.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $( ".logo" ).hover(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
        if ($('.logo').hasClass('clicked')){
              $(function(){
                $('.logo').css('background-position','-20vmin center');
                console.log("n");
                  $(".logo h3").typed({
                    strings: ["Phoenix ^250 Programming ^250 Team"],
                    typeSpeed: 75
                  });
              });
        }
        else{
            $('.logo').find( "h3" ).text("");
            $('.logo span').remove();
            $('.logo').css('background-position','center left+1.5vmin');
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: For the lazy ones, could you please be more explicit about what you are trying to do, and maybe set up a JSFiddle that shows the problem?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7xrxvmz0/ here you are

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the [source code for typed.js](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/blob/9a6c3fc/js/typed.js#L376), the function `typed()` assigns some data to the target element, and refuses to run if such data is set:

```
var $this = $(this),
    data = $this.data('typed'), // <<<
    options = typeof option == 'object' && option;
if (!data) // <<<
    $this.data('typed', (data = new Typed(this, options)));
```

Therefore you have to unset it before calling `typed()` twice:

```
$('.logo h3')
    .data('typed', null) // <<<
    .typed({
        strings: ["Phoenix ^250 Programming ^250 Team"],
        typeSpeed: 75
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that Andrea's answer while worked in your case, it would mess the effect (make it too jagged) when used with a string array with multiple elements.

If someone faces the same problem as I did, they probably could do what I did.

I used a counter to check if typed.js is called for second time and re-added .logo h3 when done so.

So, I added a wrapper.

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="logo"><h3></h3></div>
<div>
```

and then implemented

```
 if(counter==1){
 $(".logo h3").typed({
        strings: stringArrayWithManyElements,
        typeSpeed: 75
      });
}
else{
    $('wrapper').html('');
    $(".logo h3")
    .typed({
        strings: stringArrayWithManyElements,
        typeSpeed: 75
      });
}
```